# How to send different forms and let php read it as one form with $.ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

So i have an email function that i want to complete with $.ajax and i am using 3 different forms.
Also the forms are loaded with an $.ajax request and when a user clicks on a button a form will dissapear and a new form will appear. so the problem is i need to send the data form the 3 forms at the same time to the php page so it will only has to send one email.

Jquery code:

```
 //load first form
$(".volgende").click(function(){
    $("#form-1").slideToggle("slow" , function(){
        //first form will dissapear and second form will apear
        $.ajax({
            url: "include/stap-2.php", 
            success:function(result){
            $(".form>.container").hide().html(result).slideToggle();
            }
        });
        //get form data when button is clicked
        var formData1 = {
           'strnaam' : $("#strnaam").val(),
           'postc'   : $("#postc").val(),
           'plaats'  : $("#plaats").val(),
           'woning'  : $("#woning").val(),
           'leefom'  : $("#leefom").val()
        };
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            $(".stap-1").removeClass("stap-active");
            $(".stap-2").addClass("stap-active");
            $(".next-step").removeClass("volgende");
            $(".next-step").addClass("volgende-2");
        });
    });
    //when the second button is clicked
    $(".volgende-2").click(function(){
        //second form dissapear and third form apear
        $("#form-2").slideToggle("slow", function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "include/stap-3.php", 
                success:function(result){
                $(".form>.container").hide().html(result).slideToggle();
                }
            });
            // second form data stored
            var formData2 = {
                'vraagprijs' : $("#vraagprijs").val(),
                'woz'        : $("#woz").val(),
                'biedingen'  : $("#biedingen").val(),
                'uiterste'   : $("#uiterste").val(),
                'interieur'  : $("#interieur").val(),
                'exterieur'  : $("#exterieur").val()
            };
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
                $(".stap-2").removeClass("stap-active");
                $(".stap-3").addClass("stap-active");
                $(".next-step").removeClass("volgende-2");
                $(".next-step").addClass("verzenden");
                $(".verzenden", this).text("Verzenden");
                $(".verzenden", this).prop("type", "submit");
                //alert(JSON.stringify(formData2, null, 4));
            });
        });
    });
    //submit function on the third form
    $(".verzenden").click(function(event){
          //get form data from the third form
          var formData = {
          'postc'       : $('#postc').val(),
          'naam'        : $('#naam').val(),
          'telnr'       : $('#telnr').val(),
          'email'       : $('#email').val(),

          };
          $.ajax({ 
              type      : 'POST',
              url       :"include/email-verwerk.php",
              data      :formData, // send info from third form
              dataType  :"html",
              encode    : true,
              success   : function(){
                  $("form").hide();
                  $(".verzenden").hide();
              $(".form>.container").hide().html("<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Bedankt,</strong><br><p>Je bericht is succesvol verstuurd we doen ons best om binnen twee dagen te antwoorden.<br>voor dringende vragen kunt u ons bereiken op&nbsp;<span><strong>+31 645 96 22 02</strong></span></p></div>").slideToggle();
                },
                error: function(){
                            $("form").hide();
                            alert("fout");
                          }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

so when $('.verzenden') is clicked it will only submit the third form to the php page is there a way to include the data from the first and second form so that when the php pages receives it's data it will only send one complete email?

Comment: you can  use single form instead of three. divide form elements in three part first button click first part hide second button click second hide at last button form submit.

Comment: that will only get me the value of the first form for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try like this way Only single form and three div that will show and hide one by one

And at last button send all field values by ajax

```js
$("#part1-btn").click(function(){
   $("#part2").show();
   $("#part1").hide();
});
$("#part2-btn").click(function(){
  $("#part2").hide();
   $("#part3").show();
   
});


$("#part3-btn").click(function(){
  
   var part1 =   $('#part1-txt').val();
   var part2 = $('#part2-txt').val(); 
   var part3 = $('#part3-txt').val();
   var all = "part1 value:"+part1+"<br>part2 value:"+part2+"<br>part2 value:"+part3;
  
   $("#allval").html(all);  
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id ='maimform'>

<div id='part1' >
<label>part 1</label>  
<input type='text' id='part1-txt'  />
<input type='button' id='part1-btn' value='submit' />  
</div>

<div id='part2' style='display:none'>
  <label>part 2</label>  
<input type='text' id='part2-txt' />
<input type='button' id='part2-btn' value='submit' />  
</div>
  
<div id='part3' style='display:none'>
  <label>part 3</label>  
<input type='text' id='part3-txt' />
<input type='button' id='part3-btn' value='submit' />  
</div>
  
<div id='allval'>
  
</div>  

</form>
```